# Neon: maximum of four floating values inside float32x4_t vector

Tags: arm, simd, neon, cortex-a8

I want to find out maximum among the four values in one 32x4 vector.

I have one vector of type `float32x4_t`:

```
float32x4_t maxR = {10.21,10.25,23.5,24.86} //FOR EXAMPLE
```

I want to find out among this four which is max (10.21,10.25,23.5,24.86), is there an instruction to do so?

I am thinking to use `vpmax_f32` intrinsics, but came to the conclusion that this is wrong, since the return type is `float32x2_t` which is once again a vector type. So, can anyone tell me the way to do this operation?

Comment: What is float32x4_t?  An array?

Comment: no it is just a float vector . it is a part of my code ..am doing calculation over all loop and getting finally float32x4_t  maxR .and wants to find which is max among this four as want to return only maxR type of variable . I tried  maxR = max(maxR_vect.f0,max(maxR_vect.f1,max(maxR_vect.f2,maxR_vect.f3)));

Comment: sorry i did not get this ..it is a vector type float32x4_t variable .so this std::max_element is not useful with this

Comment: how can i access maxR vectors first element ??I tried maxR.v[0] which is giving me this error -> error: request for member 'v' in 'maxR', which is of non-class type 'float32x4_t

Comment: @Robinson: I think you're missing the point of the question - this is about Neon SIMD on ARM CPUs - the vectors are 128 bit SIMD registers.

Comment: @user3476225: if you find yourself needing to perform horizontal operations when working with SIMD it's often an indication that your approach to vectorisation is flawed - is there any way you can transpose your data so that you are performing this max vertically ? Maybe you could add some of your code to the question so that we can see how this fits in with the other SIMD operations you're performing ?

Comment: I am Paul.  I didn't look at the tags.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The intrinsic to extract a single value from a vector is [`vget_lane_<type>`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/chr1360928372942.html) - two appropriate pairwise maximum operations will leave you with a doubleword vector containing the desired value in both lanes, from which you can just pick it out:

```
float horz_max(float32x4_t f) {
    float32x2_t tmp;

    tmp = vpmax_f32(vget_low_f32(f), vget_high_f32(f));
    tmp = vpmax_f32(tmp, tmp);
    return vget_lane_f32(tmp, 0);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need the value in a register *right now*, and are going to be writing it back to a memory variable anyway, then it may be more efficient to instead use [`vst1_lane_f32`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/chr1359125040827.html) with an appropriate pointer to store it directly.